# DotNet 2.1 <partial> Tag using variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameters, tags, partial

```
var menuName = await UserHelper.GetRoleAsync();
...


@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuName))
{
    @Html.Partial($"LeftMenu/_{menuName}")                
}
```

I have this code, how do i convert this to a  tag?
I have tried using

```
 <partial name = "LeftMenu/_@menuName"/>
```

But while it does return the same value string this does NOT work. Is there something I'm missing in how the new tag works?

I have also tried appending .cshtml to the view name and it did not work. I even tried using the full name for this shared view

Comment: What error message, if any, are you seeing?

Comment: No error, my left menu does not display, in this case i was connected as SuperUser so it should display the _SuperUser.cshtml side menu partial, but even if i reference it directly by name in this page it does not work. I've changed references from @Html.Partial everywhere but on this page it just doesnt seem to work

Comment: Does anything show up in HTML at that line when you view the source in the web browser?

Comment: yes the code is replaced by the variable , its just that the partial does not load, it does however load using the Html.Partial or Html.PartialAsync with the same variable name. As i've stated before the only thing that does not work on the side menu is the partial tag

Comment: https://ibb.co/ec5cR8  This is the result, and yes i have tried with .cshtml extension, and the file does exist in the projet, as using the @Html.Partial retrieves it

Comment: Have you added the ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers to your _ViewImports.cshtml file? `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yup we have other tag helpers. But turns out it was a problem only on my computer, one of my coworkers tried the exact same line and it worked =_=. The mysteries of IT shall necer cease to impress me